# Why am I getting all these errors "cannot resolve symbol R" and "Content is not allowed in prolog" of .jar file?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to get in-app purchase to work with TrivialDrive sample from Google Play Store. I had all the errors out of `MyActivity.java` but now I have dozens of errors saying "cannot resolve symbol R". Gradle console says this:

```
    :app:mergeDebugResources
    [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

    C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Pay\app\src\main\res\libs\
                  android-support-v4.jar:0:0: 
    Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Pay\app\src\main\res\libs\
                  android-support-v4.jar:0:0: 
Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I don't know where that `.jar` file came from.

I assume I get all the "R" errors because the build failed but don't know what to do and inside Android Studio 1.1.0 I don't know how to do what Gradle suggests:

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

EDIT--

As requested, here is Gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dslomer64.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

EDIT #2--

Here's structure within AS 1.1.0:

[image]

```
EDIT#3--GRADLE STACKTRACE
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:compileDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Pay\app\src\main\res\libs\android-support-v4.jar:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Pay\app\src\main\res\libs\android-support-v4.jar:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Pay\app\src\main\res\libs\android-support-v4.jar:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.groovy:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\Pay\app\src\main\res\libs\android-support-v4.jar:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ValueResourceParser2.parseDocument(ValueResourceParser2.java:205)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ValueResourceParser2.parseFile(ValueResourceParser2.java:77)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.createResourceFile(ResourceSet.java:275)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.parseFolder(ResourceSet.java:250)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.readSourceFolder(ResourceSet.java:133)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataSet.loadFromFiles(DataSet.java:233)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceSet.loadFromFiles(ResourceSet.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.groovy:102)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at com.android.utils.XmlUtils.parseUtfXmlFile(XmlUtils.java:456)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ValueResourceParser2.parseDocument(ValueResourceParser2.java:202)
    ... 70 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.837 secs
```

EDIT #4--

Cannot resolve 'R' here, among others:

static int[] TANK_RES_IDS = { R.drawable.gas0, R.drawable.gas1, R.drawable.gas2, R.drawable.gas3, R.drawable.gas4 };

Here they are:

[image]

But look at `java` node--is that right?? Here's path to MainActivity:

`C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\TrivialDrive\app\src\main\java\com\dslomer64\trivialdrive\MainActivity.java`

I tried to follow instructions to create TrivialDrive, but ...................

Comment: Can you show your gradle build file?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post one of the lines where it's flagging the R.whatever?

I've had this before and for me it was due to one of the following reasons.

1) Bad path/undefined resource - fix path/create resource

2) Wrong package information. If you copied code from tutorials often it'll have their package name instead of yours.

```
package com.dslomer64.myapplication;
```

3) lastly, not sure what causes this but the solution is: File-> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Good luck

Comment: R errors here, among others: `static int[] TANK_RES_IDS = { R.drawable.gas0, R.drawable.gas1, R.drawable.gas2, R.drawable.gas3, R.drawable.gas4 };
 Refer to latest edit for more info.